# Combine values from 2 columns against unique no. into one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope you all have a great day.
I have small question for you guys. I am preparing one report which requires input from different sheets. When I combine that information into one sheet following type of arrangment is appearing.

[image: Question]

Now I also need to compare this information with other source, which requires to take information from col B & C and merge into one cell against unique value in col. A.
Here is the answer I am looking

[image: Expected Answer]

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

this will need a lil bit of prep work.

1. first excel should be like this:

[image: 1st file]

2. second one:

[image: 2nd file]

those edits are easy unmerging with the select blank trick with formula +ctrl + enter  see [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/03/07/unmerge-cells-excel/) if you dont know how

Then ull need an aditional column in the first, with this formula:
=B8&" : "&C8
That will return "Inst tag -a : Constraint pt-a". Then, ull need an array formula to match every value from that third colum we created with its respective server.
ARRAY FORMULA, ENTER WITH CTRL+SHIF+ENTER!
=VLOOKUP(D8,IF($A$20:$A$27=A8,$B$20:$C$27),2,FALSE)

$b$20:$c$27 is where u have the data to make a vlookup with the "inst tag..."

$A$20:$A$27 should be where the System is referenced in the second file.

And A8 where System is referenced in this row in the first file.

And... Voila... it works...

its pretty complicated if you are new, so let me know if you can do it.

Comment: It is Basically a Vlookup with a variable table to  search the data from, based on the result of the IF

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Power Query` *available in Excel 2010+*

Once you have developed this query, you can easily update/refresh when new data is added.

- From Excel: Get Data from Table/Range (or the equivalent in Excel 2010-2013)
- In the PQ Editor:  Select `Subsystem` column and `Fill --> Down`

  - *this will fill in the blank rows in the first column
- Select Columns 2 and 3

  - Merge columns with `" : "` as the separator
- Select Column 1

  - Group By

    - New column Name **Merged**
    - Operation:  **All Rows**
- Add Column

  - Formula: =Table.Column([Grouped],"Merged")
- Select the two-headed arrow at the top of the new "Custom" column

  - Extract Values
  - Concatenate Using Special Characters : **#(lf)** *this is the linefeed character*
- Close and Load

On the Excel worksheet
 - Format column 1 for vertical centering
 - Format column 2 for Word Wrap

[image]

All can be done from the UI except for entering the formula for the Custom Column.  But here is the M-Code:

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Subsystem No.", type text}, {"Inst. Tag", type text}, {"Constraint", type text}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"Subsystem No."}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Inst. Tag", "Constraint"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" : ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"Subsystem No."}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [#"Subsystem No."=text, Merged=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Merged")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```